# Drop down list values depending on a selected value in another drop down list

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 6 different Items:

```
Type1Item1
Type1Item2
Type1Item3

Type2Item1
Type2Item2
Type2Item3
```

of 2 different types:

```
Type1
Type2
```

I want to provide 2 DropDownLists: one to select a type, another to select items of the selected type.

Writing just

```
<select name="ItemTypeSelector" id="ItemTypeSelector">
  <option value="Type1">Type1</option>
  <option value="Type2">Type2</option>
</select><br>

<select name="ItemSelector" id="ItemSelector">
  <option value="Type1Item1">Type1Item1</option>
  <option value="Type1Item2">Type1Item2</option>
  <option value="Type1Item3">Type1Item3</option>
  <option value="Type2Item1">Type2Item1</option>
  <option value="Type2Item2">Type2Item2</option>
  <option value="Type2Item3">Type2Item3</option>
</select><br>
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/82vfmcto/)

Would allow users to select `Type2` and `Type1Item3` which does not make sense since `Type1Item3` is of type `Type1`.

**QUESTION:** Is there a way to display `Item`s of the drop down list related to the selected `ItemType`?

Comment: Handle it with JS, on type change switch items

Comment: Are you using jQuery or just Javascript?

Comment: @RaximjonKomiljonov Pure javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like the following :

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('ItemTypeSelector').addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (this.value == 'Type1') {
      for (let el of document.getElementsByClassName('Type1')) el.style.display = 'block';
      for (let el of document.getElementsByClassName('Type2')) el.style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('ItemSelector').getElementsByTagName('option')[0].selected = 'selected'
    } else {
      for (let el of document.getElementsByClassName('Type1')) el.style.display = 'none';
      for (let el of document.getElementsByClassName('Type2')) el.style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('ItemSelector').getElementsByTagName('option')[3].selected = 'selected'
    }
  }, false)
  for (let el of document.getElementsByClassName('Type2')) el.style.display = 'none';
};
```

```html
<select name="ItemTypeSelector" id="ItemTypeSelector">
  <option value="Type1">Type1</option>
  <option value="Type2">Type2</option>
</select><br>

<select name="ItemSelector" id="ItemSelector">
  <option value="Type1Item1" class="Type1">Type1Item1</option>
  <option value="Type1Item2" class="Type1">Type1Item2</option>
  <option value="Type1Item3" class="Type1">Type1Item3</option>
  <option value="Type2Item1" class="Type2">Type2Item1</option>
  <option value="Type2Item2" class="Type2">Type2Item2</option>
  <option value="Type2Item3" class="Type2">Type2Item3</option>
</select><br>
```

Comment: Absolutely cool, thanks much. But when changing a new type the old value of the old type does not get changed. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @SomeName here you go, fixed

Comment: Sorry, but your js is not dynamic. If someone adds type3 it does not work.

Comment: @RaximjonKomiljonov indeed, I'm giving the idea behind the solution, I believe he'll be able to make it dynamic ;)

Answer (score 3):

Using a `select` with `optgroup` may be a viable and simple solution for you:

```html
<select name="ItemSelector" id="ItemSelector">
  <optgroup label="Type1">
    <option value="Type1Item1">Type1Item1</option>
    <option value="Type1Item2">Type1Item2</option>
    <option value="Type1Item3">Type1Item3</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Type2">
    <option value="Type2Item1">Type2Item1</option>
    <option value="Type2Item2">Type2Item2</option>
    <option value="Type2Item3">Type2Item3</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup)

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. Your solution is very cool, but unfortunately I need a bit different look ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can toggle a "disabled" attribute. If a user selects type1 you should add a disabled attribute to all type2* options.

I have coded an example with pure Javascript.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    let current_val = '';
  document.getElementById('ItemTypeSelector').addEventListener('change', function() {
    current_val = this.value;
    
    console.log(current_val);
    for (let el of document.querySelectorAll('#ItemSelector option')) {
        el.style.display = 'none';
    }
    for (let el of document.querySelectorAll('#ItemSelector option[data-type="'+current_val+'"]')) {
      el.style.display = 'block';
    }
  }, false)
};
```

```html
<select name="ItemTypeSelector" id="ItemTypeSelector">
  <option value="type1">Type1</option>
  <option value="type2">Type2</option>
</select><br>

<select name="ItemSelector" id="ItemSelector">
  <option>Choose</option>
  <option value="Type1Item1" data-type="type1">Type1Item1</option>
  <option value="Type1Item2" data-type="type1">Type1Item2</option>
  <option value="Type1Item3" data-type="type1">Type1Item3</option>
  <option value="Type2Item1" data-type="type2">Type2Item1</option>
  <option value="Type2Item2" data-type="type2">Type2Item2</option>
  <option value="Type2Item3" data-type="type2">Type2Item3</option>
</select><br>
```

Comment: Well, disabled does not look pretty well especially if the number of types become pretty large. I'm looking for a way to hide all wrong items

Comment: Use CSS to hide disabled options XD

Comment: @SomeName I have used pure JS with a dynamic data.